# Attempting to connect to Atlas via Lambda: No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, mongodb-java, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to upload a document from a Lambda script, however I've been stuck where I keep getting the following whenever the Lambda script starts:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0-whnfd.mongodb.net: No address associated with hostname
```

The error seems obvious, however I can connect using that same URL via Mongo Compass. The Java class I'm using looks like:

```
public class MongoStore {

    private final static String MONGO_ADDRESS = "mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-whnfd.mongodb.net/test";

    private MongoCollection<Document> collection;

    public MongoStore() {
        final MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(MONGO_ADDRESS);
        final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        final MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

        this.collection = database.getCollection("test");
    }

    public void save(String payload) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.append("message", payload);

        collection.insertOne(document);
    }

}
```

Have I just misconfigured my Java class, or is there something more tricky going on here?

Comment: did you fix it? I am looking for hlep

Comment: I did not I'm afraid :(

Answer (score -3):

The same problem I had with freshly created MongoDB Atlas database, when I started the migration of my Python web application from Heroku.

So I've realised the DNS name cluster0.hgmft.mongodb.net just doesn't exist.

The magic happened when I've installed the library dnspython (my app is written in Python), with this library MongoDB client was able to connect to my database in Mongo Atlas.

Comment: the DNS name for the cluster is not propagated yet. It takes time :) It was coincident that you installed a library and it did work!